# How i can get full relative path of image in cakephp 3.1?

Tags: php, html, image, cakephp

I want to send email with images, and image has must full path,
Like, http://www.example.com/img/image-name.jpg
So, I'm using cakephp 3 framework with code:

`$this->Html->image('image.jpg', ['fullBase' => true]);`

Error accurs: `Path is not found`

I think webroot always work: `<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/image-name.jpg">` But this is not proper way.

Please suggest proper way with example.

Thanks
Mak.

Comment: You _think_ using `webroot` works? Have you actually tried it? Also where does that error occour, it doesn't read like a CakePHP error? And what _exactly_ does the `image()` call return?

Comment: I want to image with fullpath, so my email from other server can read image, I have tried with above mention code but code not generate full page : `<image src="img/image.jpg" class="" >`, have you any idea how can i manage for email?

Comment: I kinda sensed that, however you didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: When i use `<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/image-name.jpg">` it's generate same `<image src="img/image.jpg">`, when i debug email template in local machine, image and all other content display properly, but in actual email image not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the email sending, you must have to full path of the image,

```
`echo $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", [
    "alt" => "Brownies",
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6]
]);`
```

Will output:

```
`<a href="/recipes/view/6">
    <img src="/img/recipes/6.jpg" alt="Brownies" />
</a>`
```

But you have to use,

`echo $this->Html->image("logo.png", ['fullBase' => true]);`

Will output:

`<img src="http://example.com/img/logo.jpg" alt="" />`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images

This is a proper way that suggested by CakePhp framework.